# conforming to view , adding simple box shape

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have this code but still can't figure out how to display 3d cube in a view,
in swift code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentViewC: View {
    var body: some View {
        Viewer() //<-- this line
    }
}
class Viewer : UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let myView = SCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
  let myScene = SCNScene()
  myView.scene = myScene

  self.view.addSubview(myView)
    let myBox = SCNBox(width: 15, height: 10, length: 12, chamferRadius: 0)
    let myBoxNode = SCNNode(geometry: myBox)
    myBoxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    myBoxNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 1, z: 0.5, w: 0.6)
    myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(myBoxNode)
    let myLight = SCNLight()
    let myLightNode = SCNNode()
    myLight.type = SCNLight.LightType.omni
    myLight.color = UIColor.yellow
    myLightNode.light = myLight
    myLightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -30, y: 30, z: 60)
    myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(myLightNode)
}

}
```

just to see cube in a view would be great in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318581/how-to-update-a-scenekit-scene-with-swiftui im finding this usefull

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  ContentViewC.swift
//  Lightning
//
//  Created by Edward Taylor on 22/12/2022.
//







import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentViewC: View {
 @State var rotationAngle = 0

var body: some View {

    VStack{
        SceneKitView(angle: $rotationAngle)
            .frame(alignment: .center)

    }
  }
}

struct SceneKitView: UIViewRepresentable {

 @Binding var angle: Int

func degreesToRadians(_ degrees: Float) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(degrees * .pi / 180)
}

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) -> SCNView {

    let sceneView = SCNView()
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    sceneView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 0, height: 1)

    return sceneView
}

func updateUIView(_ sceneView: SCNView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) {

        let pixel = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
        let pixelnode = SCNNode(geometry: pixel)
        pixelnode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        pixel.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green

        pixelnode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -1, 0)

        let inttofloat = Float(self.angle)

         let rotation = SCNAction.rotate(by: self.degreesToRadians(inttofloat), around: SCNVector3(1, 0, 0), duration: 5)

         pixelnode.runAction(rotation)

         sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(pixelnode)

}
typealias UIViewType = SCNView

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).